# Wait for server response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I'm using Flask and JSON to communicate between python and javascript. I want the program to wait for a response from the server before switching tabs. Here's my javascript code

```
            window.onload = function() {
// setup the button click
                document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
                    doWork()
                };
            }

            function doWork() {
                $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", JSON.stringify([document.getElementById("URL").value, document.getElementById("term").value, document.getElementById("pages").value]), function(){

                });
                // stop link reloading the page
             event.preventDefault();
             //HERE: Wait for response from server
             window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/results";
            }
        </script>
```

Is this possible using Flask and JSON, or do I have to use something else?

Comment: that is what the promise for the ajax call is for.... Put the line in the empty function

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` event is not defined

Comment: Check out the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/.  Specifically, note the "success" parameter.  It's a callback for when a successful response is returned.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by wait for a response. Try to put success function block inside ajax post call and do not put anything in there, even after a response if you do not have any actions, it will maintain its same state?